# Using PHP and cURL to resize a remote image

Tags: php, curl, image-resizing

Last night I asked how to use a url as an argument in 'imagecreatefrom...()' without using fopen(). cURL was presented as my answer, but when I try plugging it in, as well as messing around with some suggestions I found around the web, I just can't get it to work.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://curious.astro.cornell.edu/images/xraysun.gif'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1); 
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$image = imagecreatefromstring($data);

$thumb_width = 200;
$thumb_height = 150;

$width = imagesx($image);
$height = imagesy($image);

$original_aspect = $width / $height;
$thumb_aspect = $thumb_width / $thumb_height;

if ( $original_aspect >= $thumb_aspect )
{
// If image is wider than thumbnail (in aspect ratio sense)
$new_height = $thumb_height;
$new_width = $width / ($height / $thumb_height);
}
else
{
// If the thumbnail is wider than the image
$new_width = $thumb_width;
$new_height = $height / ($width / $thumb_width);
}

$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor( $thumb_width, $thumb_height );

// Resize and crop
imagecopyresampled($thumb,
$image,
0 - ($new_width - $thumb_width) / 2, // Center the image horizontally
0 - ($new_height - $thumb_height) / 2, // Center the image vertically
0, 0,
$new_width, $new_height,
$width, $height);

imagejpeg($thumb);
```

This is what `imagejpeg()` outputs:

```
����JFIF��>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v80), default quality ��C      $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342��C     2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222����"��   ���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������� ���w!1AQaq"2�B����    #3R�br� $4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������?��)�P< ����ZxZUZ�R����4GR�UJ�R����2���S�>�uw�K #��6��b1�V1��#�85k�+nIO�hZh�7.�e�r;Weoḭrȹ����w-R����ӕS��>y�;复����{�B��F z��(ZF�$��U��YIh�;�7P)�F�Cs&G�@�>���^OY�El��|�u�H&��mͶ9B���Zq��(\3�<�;1���R��":ȳ���'>��s�MD����e/���*�$�o��Z41��`7�Ӛ����Ȗ#�Ðx��A������t��T�ܮ4rWp��{V|��]}��N�f&�%����\Bcb�#��[]MXƵ>ddȘ�kBH� �A3ƫAܢ�Q���*N��g�R�Eb)�T�j2*�9���)�QL�ĸH��J��l���z�N�ME���v=*4�*%N��֕0:�ޝn�~���};���_��:j(��L��?��[�l����/ 1ޔG ̈́�p�g$c�hUd�����5�ԩ���滗IDB@   �e }3T�m��.@;���֭B�$O��%0���(�ZI6����}Er�腡 AVe�1�s�ǧC�1#�m��Y�nM�A���WbH#.�\�����֙4�6��#�;������m�w,Z��)��p9�8���jz�f5P���J�IK�/�-��c����$��&��J��v��SՓk�q4��X�7F�4�gX����T��>�����[ȧa�J��R��)PФ���*�9h;2k�VR�Y�� ϶*�Β�Q���!G<`���S��<�*�P:�G�_Ӛlw%ʰA�����GX����9+�6KY�J����"u���(�B�"�yA���9�Iop����eO�z�lg2��"pRG:ђ:Uy""��4WKa&G#�a� V �賂�O�����̆J���ʘ��+�;�%jVer(�����qԲ��E�D��F+6z�c�I9.    ���)d��+E?;O�a�8��WY�m��E�_m��$�n�s������IG���Us��=�y�3����΍UZ�z4B2K�J͌/�:}i]fr���=03'\w���m��p�2|��<���5,��.#(���-��K�ٚ���gO�x�������Mv%�d�c�@'v}=��N{k[�kF�i�y%Y%���~uGːFm���7�"1�zZ(�n���l��P��$k;�H�n�����[��I;}�ݭ��|��zdbS�ZHQ~PX�{�����Cp�,�;�$e����qBM6�5��.�"�e���U����C�pS��E[�y(G�"�A��|U=��5���JHb�F��c����b���H"�6_,d0����`�b�ؼ�EZӭ��;�{��#(�z�G?�K6����,<�e���=*9���'�\f�bYa�7Nꌹ�A���lSU���m��;��Է�pT�v��9�UmB����n��#��-;!�������#��#ڹ�J܆/����,�Ep���e�:�S�Y��B�i�Xm]X�gN�Iֵ��k:U��~����(r�� )�(��&Qԝ*�u]j�u�=:��X1t@���x�V֒>�$�тȁT�� *��7��$��4��|1*�    �͎�?�Z��5%ҧk�P �<�֪Z�r��B������}�!T�sF�4{�����*�e+�H�II4�6u]k�ȇ1��N�xA�*��0����UC`�u?�V��ꕃ�*7`���Ҡ��od1F�1�����Z��  <�2�,�nX� ��7�:d��#,�w�e�����J�t�ʿ���kM�ۨ�EX���^rA�y⡚7�/p���Ѓߊ�-����6ǉЙw��}* ������R$EP@#����k+j�J�[��?��,bs�]��ܒ3^�}�4����%�N�01���+ƅ��v�Ll�(@X��j����E���<� �O�:iQ�����n�2�i�΃�OQ�#�G)A��'!2a6��ќp:Z�|C�-��p6;c���Z共��27��Z� 7�[t:pʢ�����;װk�T�"��鰎�֩^_Gv�P�VfWyD��U>���r����A��]T(���S]�<3}k2^�zS�� �v����c3*0�����,��֬�UTՈ��A�\N������|�>k��������ҡYt����$~?�c^v6V���PZ\����d���0��~������Yf3��c�z�g�U�!w���Lq��u�X!�����e$�;�+�w7b�iL�� ����j��y2�HŔ�T��S���M�M��Xʸ<�ydu� ����,�-��9PcauX�;>����͊��m�"[F<��R��O�_J�<�B�����$6w(8��j�1�v#����vzg8�S�X;٥��  ��a�/���IE�Ù-����eB 'v0�|�ƧHJM7 ��D�G��Ԉ��@�c2۱�ñ��ZΩt!��<��� g��=��7!�M{�<����L�\��>c��@�U�+�g�cP�n��3�$��������S^��w&���;�<�u���Tr��$�BCl�)��r"e�s����U������{�(�y�� ����1����i�,���#��v�Đ<����n�U�#���֢j�]49#�.�#*���Zx�Yf�E�"I�n��ڢV�������$��������[�&H��  ��A�v�W�P�e&H�%�d����My�]o1��@l�1ӯ��騾M�3N����c�jT�9�M���FA�6�����țrB�|��8\�ߥs:��L?.�^�6�����6U�y�8���@*�=:���i=I��3��� � "�Iֽ��yX��QJ�V�����b3U��CJF�e��WE�L�b?o��s5miS&���CG?���d9����N�锘�"+K)ʎ1��zTI,�p���О���$M�YY1c��g���Y�L�~F@�g�$�;  d�8%�"��&Y��3��z�>�82�1���!��HN���dEC��p��=���Q���9>Z�Pv��$��>�:5�$��bo?�R��!�9�Ǩ=��1u4�8t!$^\y==x��8�>b    bS+�{��J����s���īl?���P�m��Q&\:���8�⡑ƞ[<(Y�X��L�(yH��>�����Yw3��=���B�a�v��Ms"  �awd�z��޲�B���hfb�����Ϧi��ɔ��b@RF01���Q-�o*30E�1�-���1M;��N�$�b�#���s�c�������,p,��&M�BH��P]�S������c�i�I���L��ljpF=x�����@�ƚ#3���x���ʴ/��\i�B  @�����#�ګ^��g*N�S�ګ�̒8�R�ǵkd��k�HV�pd ��`c4�h���wg��S뎔�B$ܒ�*(-׀ �Җ�s)v��>E����M=|�@҈�ۖ;���c���~����Rq�WC1�j2�FrGA���e��v�&�pkV�EisT�zJ�-z���1H��R��<�nD��CU���:��D��ǯjlΓoT�Q��T���5�sW1ޱ���=�4���d�iH�1V8_Zpx�F!/ʋ�ϧ�di�"Ehdp����j�82���*��{zׇR��|����+�W���<�6�'$w�_֤�$�A� 2��wv<��-���ꊒ�\(���2�m�b̀xON `����g2*�s�΄�����N}�m��!��a������5�ĩ�Yc9�o9E'���b���@��3�z��*�0#/���sX����J{�y`p� �f�S��RGd���͹Cǌ��4�w.�   h���oS�����MA��Z��wS[\1�q,��@8:�x'��$A���ˌ�{�SSZ�o.�c:�^1� Ѷ�eiX#7�Τ63���5\ʖ���� �#�)n7:`����jQM�a̱0 K�H�O�[p�R��{��U%����)�iM�$�^���S������k9�U}~�%^��,ev`��2J���WO��|Ĝ�>�w�T�Oh�) +�#���c�ƙon�&�    ���S:'��7`�T���w=i�l�S[�<���1_((۱s��֩[��"ƥ����>��M"2��b��@��V-c��]���^F�ps�?.?Z�+-�3��x� y-��w�?�Q��d�ӎp8���MQ��E*��2���|VN��e@=�jSWI�\����Jj��J^��Gc��2�u��������"�Ii'��v�+3D�a�5f���a��Im�����n��~J�Ei��Ż�a�������R#���������;V-��:Zŋx�8����Kӝ]yt`    ��n�r1I�үY]%�r����]R7[�Ҥ�-������)�<�O�!�ԏ| [��cL��FR0�ۥ�� �ݴt�?���yq��; m��H=;���+Kݠ�l�z���f��s�>�:�r!qTxQ�O�s�����8�2DC(�s��)@���J� ���{������ItA�M�(���$��sUa��bC�9�;�ǽXG=����g�#�;c�~5n��"�pKw'|h��GOj�nU��)��$w$wp n��^���1yp�#�V=:����O.��a�9��[ֵ�Y���+� ��Y��5ڽ�L])և$]��j�;�n`��W ��=�y����x���P��is�5��N�`���3���:���k����,�ҵu*֚�W�A��R�/q|�p�J�Pl���9�p?J�!��d��Z�`#�G`?¬�l�,R�"�!�Q�h00$c�"�o���K��WFj��i�*��O�ޭiڒ�H$X��,��v���j)�+�Y�ڣ���)��ܼ�  ���b���j�׆d�-��c��z��/�`�pI�*���I��c�$�ϭvP��ni:�(dҊ�#f�#櫹�V(�15���4SI��<��*>�"���F8 ��.E��e�ƴ-�p�$�VP��W��S;����wL���"G������!���ås�\2p�Jӳ�%��`���d¹�Ni�'�a� s\��ֆ�tu-� 0:V�\3���kd���zW?���M�_�>=ZX�����ʸ����Q�;��I�s\�l[���*�4a��d��{t�Z�!��}��1\����#�`���OC���>��{6п�W���Ey5�ΛwV!���R��,q#�r�w}�z����"������9�}Ej��t$)I�X�O�]]69H�r�)����k�ڴ�f���G=�B�e[� ����^��`|�byw^B�L}j��dܟ�R����>��H4�@��b�w��R�}�Ջ[�f�D�s�ێ�F['���H2F�ZF�)�_bq��v���#�m�o�PJ�$9��#;�R���Л��'�U\��<�!p�2q�ͼ�E��M������U�MTG,��rF��� �e���c�=k��a��l[ij��2���ۜ�^�����j&�=��޽jT]�z�▃�J��=���5t�y�k��Bƕ��Mh��T�ƓE4�*�f�����E3�� R6���V��L��d��T�SE p��RS�h[�w0Ʊ�#"�)�O��Vs�d��s��I.����.�*�z�Ҵ��Y����� �d�Q^}l�)���-D)ò�2�Nrd�~��(`��x�Ɗ+8���bٙs��O�+��Z̖�YX�����(��ti��G-J�[233�����$�i�Mjș�Q&�*�9Ɍ-Q�EH��c �Eg<��EPd���
```

A `var_dump` on `data` gives basically the same thing for thousands of lines on the site:

```
string(123362) "GIF89a������!)19J��������������������������!�!�!�!�!�!�)�)�)�)�)�1�1�1�1�9�9�9�B�B�J�R�Z�c�k�s�������޽��c��1��!���{��{��Z��J��9��)��!�����޵�֥�ƌ��s��R��B��1��)����������Δ�Ƅ��9��1��!�����ޭ�΄��{��R��B����J��9�ޥ�֌��k��������{��s���������19Bs{����JR����Zck���������������,��@� H�@�8q (h�@�"lx�D���Сŏ�I8r�Ǌ&㘄�1���!E�,`����8Sތ3g�J�rz�왳蜟s��,:�hS�$��<��S�D�NM���V�N�^e���T�9�|��v�ڶn��Mjq��u������˽[�x�pE�=N���ǈ-=0��䅔R0���A `4hͦ?�<�t��\�M��l�j����ܾy��-@Rǖ�*������JG����#k������e���Cໜ�?-��y5΁�f��9{3$�9��uj�(]����z�u�U�y�VW�)�_\�$a��%��Hj���[i��Y<]��X�a`Sf���R%�՗M,���K%�$�z�dBHݏE6�F�U���-$�o���Yg���i���䑶���l��v�o[��� �en�X䏃-�\r,I��c'���F�4I|n�RL�!�ލ!j�{6Q�Q/���I �{O�G`�Vu�aSY�'�ZN(a�V�|&�W`�"���|2��֪���j[�J����k��%`|*����6x!{q-�3���x*�g���y�fGY榛qP��@��%t�i�k�F�����[����֤��n�o��rY�o��ɛq�f$.�'�{tU�'G4Ť�76�w��4�u��t����a��.{_�a�Z�ʽ�묺���|o��\�+ ����j��+� ���2']t�>��H����@���S?���4_H��s�ڠJ�����)���J�)D�����B}�\���Pf�E�)�gVNIo���ko�a�[ۘ����c���0M�)��t�]��Kn�hRQ��M�UF]��Wj�r�����ϫ����C���T�HѻC��B-������C'���H_] ���<�W����G�����<�Pg?���#�����/>�������;�3�L�h��6�'R�!�Qcp{�4"��d�`�қhR%���]}�R�^C�z�k5^ڗo��xbA�2�9*&�YQ�,�B��%@��T��!�mg���Өf��Aw=��������I��ǻ^��w>�)1���"����'���XD ��E,��]̢�0*��T�"�p=:�qd��8�-�Q�׻��H�$�ωK������ (׹�����(�1�Y`A$��w��o�r����~}�^[rMs9�$�:-9["ϣ�j��&3JP��ZMeh� �������{����W<"�o�Sf2�xEb:��X|���;汚u�#6��M6�������)G7���朣9��Mq�����C� �nΓ����>�Y�O{���t\#��E1:1����!���Nr8�s$b0D2�h���]�H��`���(ŦKY:\q��H�P=<ʓOPh����,���d!�\�UR�/�v�Y �|�l�����<���-��(U�jq��̪;�Y�rs���*X�i�yڡ���Z�zO����p}+[��V>ԁ|�^��W���}�k��v�~��������=�`�X�浭n-k<��F�F�}���j�"�ܥD�J  u��0�����[S�ji5�I�(x�y�0�JHL�+�V"�<�)�r_x3A�*fF����(��}��(ը*э��*5�HNm�1�] (A�Iϴ���d��]�*��N6���CckX?H�~`�����.��N���7��� �+���p�� ? ��GL�[�8��W��?������X�구l�g<��G-:q������:�ve<�Y ��#�I��e�Է��\�M�%�V��K�Mgz3��''�AOupZ�����dNs�����fz7�ټ�Ùg��w��L'��� b��o~�:W��S�sc�hD��C"K�q�S��x�2R�A虂���N�h~�yq��8�%��àd ����^��(�i�1��,�6�i:❇�6+��zVvC���o}����"������do�ڢ�y�w0�� �9�� T��T;6(v���sm�z��F��=}�h����f��{-�O7����� t��m�`jOu�m-kO���.�;���������6��U�� X�N��]�׵z�ߌ㝡���e�!��֕����N�T�L_����_Ř�t�k����>'b�Wi'`��fɆj>7jߦlBl�fi�l�fm��v5�k�vl��kd'k�6w��k6�i�kh}���s3�|�uc��V��Y�tU�FU��FU$d�D;�r!�B?A-"9��0����$�&�I �Q�8h�(pq{ʢC�s>b䃝^��U:�h��r�7_Us��`��`�Vn}t�/�a    ��i��t�V~@J0�ht7�DWtE�:���ij5�����+Ƈ�Hv�t�VjCPk��~>�m��t��k"��w�l�f�C �XtD�GGt�xtfgk�uw�t��u�v�8�ӆl�6m8��v��t��k8m�6cphs/�r8V|��c`V��GbhE��<,�r!?!)���Qw$�S��@r�$��eQ���,W+>�5�3=P��No�4h��ho5O�GY�VYvX��s;Gns8}x�a-�a �a f���t�6����ؒFWt:`w��kCG�u��F��vЈw�V��i9�j�t��s�&b�&���CЌ��iK����u��uF7��v�I�vCpH�p����u-��C����s_wwlW��H�v+iw�6j��j_�tG��:�5�w�k��~ �a &iٸ��Ic��W��c6�U��G��C�s;�R#+�"�S(�s-%pR�&O7�4&#:C4EE�EcN�y���V�r�5Yp�`0�a�a Ynf'����|H��8��Ƈ+��R�~��uE��(��8�A0�N��k�֝9���&�6��6tD�v�w'��m爣6k'pl�6�@ ���s���:l]7l1@t}�t�ɝ90^v�����+�w���fi�8d����tȈj���9@ W!��:`i�j����l��v�i�G���`qh���~��x5��u�^%P�dUu=�H*Sq(�d�649�Q����dI�c+V�מ)mG
```

A `var_dump` on `$image` right after `curl_close()` gives:

```
resource(65) of type (gd)
```

Also if I try using `imagejpeg()` before all the resizing code, it still gives basically the same thing. I'm stuck :/

---

Even with Musa's fix of setting the content header, it still just displays the raw image data:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www...../image31.jpg'); //Actually full URL in code
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1); 
$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$image = imagecreatefromstring($data);
//var_dump($image);
$thumb_width = 200;
$thumb_height = 150;

$width = imagesx($image);
$height = imagesy($image);

$original_aspect = $width / $height;
$thumb_aspect = $thumb_width / $thumb_height;

if ( $original_aspect >= $thumb_aspect )
{
// If image is wider than thumbnail (in aspect ratio sense)
$new_height = $thumb_height;
$new_width = $width / ($height / $thumb_height);
}
else
{
// If the thumbnail is wider than the image
$new_width = $thumb_width;
$new_height = $height / ($width / $thumb_width);
}

$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor( $thumb_width, $thumb_height );

// Resize and crop
imagecopyresampled($thumb,
$image,
0 - ($new_width - $thumb_width) / 2, // Center the image horizontally
0 - ($new_height - $thumb_height) / 2, // Center the image vertically
0, 0,
$new_width, $new_height,
$width, $height);

header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
imagejpeg($thumb);
```

Tried using a jpeg to start with just to see if it changed anything, but still had the same result, gibberish.

---

---

After getting the image to display I tried making a function for this code in my header:

```
function resizeJpeg($url, $thumb_width, $thumb_height)
{
echo "URL: " . $url . "<br />";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1); 
$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$image = imagecreatefromstring($data);

$width = imagesx($image);
$height = imagesy($image);

$original_aspect = $width / $height;
$thumb_aspect = $thumb_width / $thumb_height;

if ( $original_aspect >= $thumb_aspect )
{
// If image is wider than thumbnail (in aspect ratio sense)
$new_height = $thumb_height;
$new_width = $width / ($height / $thumb_height);
}
else
{
// If the thumbnail is wider than the image
$new_width = $thumb_width;
$new_height = $height / ($width / $thumb_width);
}

$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor( $thumb_width, $thumb_height );

// Resize and crop
imagecopyresampled($thumb,
$image,
0 - ($new_width - $thumb_width) / 2, // Center the image horizontally
0 - ($new_height - $thumb_height) / 2, // Center the image vertically
0, 0,
$new_width, $new_height,
$width, $height);

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
return $thumb;
// Also tried 'return imagejpeg($thumb);' and simply 'imagejpeg($thumb);'
}
```

And tried using it in this way:

```
$imageData = resizeJpeg('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1e/Stonehenge.jpg', 150, 150);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
$imageSrc = "<img src = '" . imagejpeg($imageData) . "' />";
```

Does it have to be in file or is there a way to make it see it as an URL?

Comment: What's the problem?  It seems that you are getting image output just fine.

Comment: It's displaying that image data all over the page instead of the actual image. See above.

Comment: is this the whole file, nothing but the file?

Comment: @iRector, You're not trying to directly include this in a page, are you?  You need to access this like you would any other image.  `<img src="yourscript.php" />`

Comment: works for me copied whole script above, get nice pic of sun

Comment: Well that makes sense... I put all that code into "resize-image.php" with only php tags around the code. I then put `$imageSrc = "<img src = 'resize-image.php'/>"; echo $imageSrc;` in my site's php and it's now displaying the "unable to find image: '?'" on the page. I also tried just doing it in plain html `<img src = "resize-image.php" />` with no luck. Am I still missing something...?

Comment: visit resize-image.php in the browser - get anything?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I figured it out. Just a issue with my MAMP root folder. Thank you all for the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I know you're probably sick of all these questions, but I have one more. I'm trying to make a resize function out of that code, but out of everything I've tried it either won't display an image at all, spew image data all over the page, or have a broken image. Code is above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the mime type for the browser to render the data as an image, this can by done by setting the content type header before you output the image.

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```